# Does type of input to the neural network matter?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, caffe

This is definitely a newbie question.
Video classification task in caffe .

I have a neural network I have to train with videos(group of images).
I can choose to change the shape of the input to the network from several options.

In all cases I assume that the network architecture (arrangement and number of layers) & learning parameters (LR/decay/Regularization/etc) to be constant.

For example I could choose to give my input to the network as one of the following.

1) batch_size x (no_of_imgs*no_of_channels) x height x width {3 dimensional input}

2) batch_size x no_of_imgs x no_of_channels x height x width {4 dimensional input}

3) batch_size x no_of_channels x no_of_imgs  x height x width {4 dimensional input}

How would the input shape influence the accuracy of the network?

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely advice you to choose second set up. In this case you can make use of a different spatial and spectral properties and invariances of images which might help you in better learning when using convolutional architectures. In first set up - much of both spatial and spectral information is lost. In third - a little bit less but still some spectral information might be lost which may harm your learning process.

Comment: I have looked at the [C3D version of caffe](https://github.com/facebook/C3D) which also does video classification. But with 3D Convolution It takes the input  batch_size x no_of_channels x no_of_imgs x height x width {4 dimensional input}. I intend to use the normal version of caffe. I had tried the 1) approach with only an accuracy of 5%.

Comment: I think that it also would be ok - probably the filter is designed in this way and it will work fine :)

Comment: Hi I just went through the [Two stream paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1406.2199c) agin and found that They actually  give an input of w×h×2L where L is number of frames. But generally caffe accepts input of channels*w*h . And I'm not sure how they stacked the 2l as well for eg all Rs and then B and G. {R1,R2,... B1,B2...G1,G2....} or the {R1,B1,G1,R1,G2,B2.....} ...